# Why does this bug happen in KDE with X11 on Debian?

Tags: debian, xorg

I have a long running job in a shell in Debian-Linux, in which I use a lot of other tabs with heavy-load tasks that change.
I just started guvcview and now this happened to the title bar (yes, I'm using a XP theme, but it also happens on other themes).

[image: Weird text bug]

This reminds me of the "Start Wandows Ngrmadly"-message that Windows displays under certain conditions. I've encountered that bugs on quite a lot of different systems, but I could never reliably reproduce it. It doesn't destroy the usability or anything, I'm just curios why this happens. Is there any explanation?